# Как заменять background-image при результате оператора if

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

Товарищи, подскажите пожалуйста каким образом можно менять картинку `background-image` в стилях при выполнении условия `if` на простом js или же на vue

картинок около 80, значит условий будет столько же, может есть какая-то альтернатива?

[image: пример кода]

Comment: Стоит более подробно сформулировать вопрос. Что за if, откуда картинки берутся.

Comment: картинки на локалке, в классах прописаны как `.personimgPloKoon {
background-image: url('starship2.png');
background-size: 100% 100%;
height: 200px; 
}`   if прописан в js файле, мне нужно чтобы в зависимости от выбранного "имени", менялся его аватар.

Comment: вам надо продумать архитектуру, на стороне сервера уже выдавать в нужное место как имя пользователя так и аватар, if тут делать не нужно.

Comment: В вашем случае у вас есть объект `person` в JavaScript коде. Уже в нём надо что бы была ссылка на картинку аватара `person.avatarUrl` например. И прямо её и выводить.

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/ffad68087fec3343357e1dc1d5c7e7e9.png   Дмитрий, можете подсказать?

Answer (score 3):

В архитектуре есть проблема, надо её продумать более рационально.

Если на сервере есть список пользователей, то для каждого пользователя надо хранить ссылку на аватар

Часть таблицы, пример:

Users
- Name
- AvatarUrl

И уже на клиента что бы приходил объект person в котором уже есть информация по аватаре `person.avatarUrl`

If-ы тут не нужны.

Если базы нет, есть только соответствие имён и аватаров, то сделать можно просто.
Заводим список имён и аватаров в виде объекта JavaScript (ассоциативный массив)

```
var namesAvatars = {
  "Name1": "avatar1Url",
  "Name2": "avatar2Url",
  "Name3": "avatar3Url",
  "Name4": "avatar4Url"
   /* ...  */
}
```

Получаем аватар по имени

```
var avatarUrl = namesAvatars[name];
```

Comment: Там архитектура куда сложнее, там идет соотношение имен к другим значениям. Допустим 1 место = 3 имени, 2 место = 10 имен. Места достаются по api как и все остальное. Поэтому я думал сделать через if, но это очень бы нагружало весь процесс, т.к. имя-аватар около 85шт

Comment: я архитектуры не знаю, как там извлекать, но если хотите через if аналог, смотрите мой код в ответе в самом низу, эта ситуация. Решается без if-о, и выполняется моментально.